# populating a jQuery Select2() control with JSON data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, jquery-select2

I have done the same thing several times (also on the same project actually) and it works fine. I have an issue just with this instance of the same code. 
First of all I select some data from a db table:

```
$azioni = $pdo->query("SELECT id_az, concat_ws('-',Descrizione, RGE) as descrizione 
                       FROM azioni_head 
                          JOIN sofferenze ON sofferenze.id_soff = azioni_head.id_soff
                        ORDER BY Descrizione")
               ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This gives me an array like this (just first few items):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_az] => AZ000000126
            [descrizione] => Acciaierie Weissenfels S.p.A.-n/d
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_az] => AZ000000017
            [descrizione] => Acofer S.p.A.-n/d
        )
)
```

Then I convert this array in a Json array doing:
    `var azioni = <?php echo json_encode($azioni); ?>;`
and finally I populate a Select2 using these data but this time the select2 has no items inside.
If I try to view the array once it is encoded using `alert(azioni.join( ));` I get:

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],

Finally I run:

```
$('#cod_az').select2({ placeholder: "Scegli", data: azioni });
```

**What is wrong? Why I cannot use this array to populate Select2 with the data? It works in other section of my application!**

**Edit**
this is the result of console.log(azioni) in firebug:

```
[
Object { id_az="AZ000000126",  descrizione="Acciaierie Weissenfels S.p.A.-n/d"}, 
Object { id_az="AZ000000017",  descrizione="Acofer S.p.A.-n/d"}, 
Object { id_az="AZ000000039",  descrizione="ADANI SAS DI ADANI PAOLO & C. S.p.A.-n/d"}, 
Object { id_az="AZ000000019",  descrizione="Administration Speciale ...NG S.A. en faillite-n/d"}
]
```

Comment: @Tushar same result as with join

Comment: `console.log(azioni)` and look at your Javascript console. `alert()` is useless for debugging.

Comment: So... question answered?

Comment: no. This json array is the only one that I cannot use to populate the data in the select2 (all the other conditions are the same) while the same code works in other pages on the same application!

Comment: Well, since the array is obviously fine, and we do not see what you're doing with it, we can't help a lot further at this point.

Comment: Which result do you get from of this: alert(azione[0]["id_az"]) and alert(azione[0]["descrizone"])?

Comment: @deceze sorry! forgot a line of code in my question! my fault!

Comment: *"The objects that the users can select from should be passed as an array with __each object containing `id` and `text`__ properties."* https://select2.github.io/options.html

Comment: whoah! didn't notice that! this solves the issue. Will you move it to an answer so i can mark it as close?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To debug, use `console.dir(azioni);` to inspect your objects.

Change your `id_az` and `descrizione` keys to `id` and `text`

```
var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'item1' }, { id: 1, text: 'item2' }];

$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
  data: data
})
```

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

By default jquery select2  expects data to be in id/text format.

Answer (score 0):

That's the standard and desired behavior. What you want is examine the content of the object instead of getting the `[object Object]` string, which is the correct result of the `toString()` method.

There are several ways to examine a structure of arrays and objects in Javascript. What I do is pretty simple and works well but it has a slight *twist* in it.

```
var data = JSON.parse(input);
// data now contains the JSON data
// to print it on-screen I do:
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This might sound strange to re-code the data into JSON, but you have done a full turn in:

- parsing JSON
- rendering JSON

So you really can be confident that the `input` string is valid JSON and what you see in the `alert()` is the actual content. I don't know an easier method than this.

**EDIT:** Mind you, it is not the same as printing the `input` string directly. The *decode/recode* turn-around really does a lot for you: it shows that it can decode the JSON and shows you how it actually is after decoding. For example, the order of properties is not preserved.

Comment: Thanks pid! now I have one more confirmation I have a valid json array. But the issue about why I cannot use that json to populate a Select2 remains the same

Comment: Yes, I see. The title is a bit misleading I think I'll fix it for you so that the right people see it.